# Past Simple with Present Continuous in one sentence

Tags: tense

I've got a question related to tenses. 
I am watching a sad movie that is making me cry and my friend is sending me a text message making me smile. I want to tell him about it so is this sentence okay?

> I'm watching a movie that's making me cry and your message made me smile.

Should I write I have been watching or get rid of Past Simple?

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is perfectly natural.  It's fine to mix tenses in the same sentence if the actions describe different things which are not directly related.  In your example, you are *in the process* of watching a movie, so it's fine to use the present continuous to say that the movie is *making* you cry.  Meanwhile your friend's message is not an ongoing action, so it's fine to use the simple past to say the message *made* you smile.

Ongoing action vs. one time event, and, aside from the sequence of events and the implied contrast, you choose not to relate the two events.  Another example:

> I **was walking** my dog when I **found** a rare coin lying in the street.

Again, one event was going on when the second event occurred.  But it would also be fine to say:

> I had been walking my dog when I **found** a rare coin.

In this case, you want to imply that the two events *are* related.  The first event was ongoing up to the moment of the second event.   The past perfect continuous implies that event *stopped* the moment you found the coin.  In the same way, it would be fine to say:

> The movie **had been making** me cry before your message **made** me smile.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!